# Sticky Navigation Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the link: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j44xdv3m/5/)

```
$('.main-menu').addClass('fixed');
```

How come the fixed element is flickering whenever the fixed class is added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're constantly removing and re-adding the `fixed` CSS attribute because everytime you scroll, the top offset changes.  What you want to do is store it in a variable on load, then compare against that variable.
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j44xdv3m/6/

Comment: I should have known when i logged it and there were a bunch of different numbers. Thanks!